# Unable to register the iOS device token to azure notification hub using ionic 3 FCM token using Java

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, token, azure-notificationhub, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am Using FCM with ionic 3 plugin for IOS app, while trying to register device token to Azure notification hub, with the below FCM token generated by ,

```
this.fcm.getToken().then(token => { /*saving token here*/});

c-NtgjPB8Rg:APA91bEk0bvwec5tGjzCYQ_0I2axwpFmuRJ1JRUpHwdcTkVV1J1AR_Xb3p7qYp68il0y_TmiJ4ecQYDQdCFDLwzA-KALA_I7Q2tUOW2zszsDA0lPD8tvo0IlRYhf1Z5KwhR5u6h02z2w
```

I am passing it using Java code with AppleRegistration for AppleRegistrationDescription, 
getting error,

**messaging.NotificationHubsException: Error: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request - One or more characters in device token is not a hexadecimal digit.**

Referring the below link for Azure Notification Hub,
[Azure Notification HUB with Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/blob/master/notificationhubs-rest-java/NotificationHubs/src/com/windowsazure/messaging/AppleRegistration.java)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the spaces from APNS Token before pass it to the Azure Registration.

Comment: Do you mean the dashes and underscores?